# reverse proxy shall act as a cache and provide a website under a different domain

Tags: reverse-proxy, rewrite, cache, url, nginx-reverse-proxy

Assume a webserver providing a language version of a website accessable under the URL

http://www.website-a.com/zh-hans/some-otherstuff/index.php

I want to setup a reverse proxy for one language version for a specific region with a different domain. The user shall access that website via the reverse proxy (caching and automatically or on demand updating the cache):

http://www.website-b.cn/some-otherstuff/index.php

can I teach let's say nginx or caddy to whenever someone starts a request to website [www.website-b.cn](http://www.website-b.cn) to add /zh-hans right after the domain and grab the nswer from the cached version which is updated regularly or on demand? double content and similar problems can be neglected at this stage.

Sorry for not being that specific, just asking if someone has already experience with such a scenario and can give some recommandations how to solve such a problem or if a reverse proxy with cache and rewriting requests is a dead end.